# [] wildcard doesn't work

Tags: 20.04, wildcards

I was watching a training video for learning Linux wildcards and I learnt some of them like {},*,?,[] etc. After that I wanted to make some practice and tried to create 300 directory in a folder which their names goes like folder 1,folder 2,folder 3 ..., then I tried to create 100 file which their names goes like file1.txt,file2.txt,file3.txt ... And then I wrote these commands to the terminal:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kOMn.png

I realized that I couldn't create what I want so I tried another wildcard which is "{}" and after that I wrote these commands to the terminal:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/E576w.png

As you can see, at the end of the process I was successful but I still don't know why "[]" wildcard didn't work. In the video I watched, the man was wrote the commands like the first picture I left and after that the folders were be created. Can someone explain me why that wildcard didn't work ?

Comment: Just because someone made a video and placed it on-line doesn't mean that it is correct.  For starters, perhaps he didn't use the bash shell?

Comment: Unfortunately, even [tldp.org](https://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm) says, that `{}` would be a wildcard. But that is not true, it's a very different mechanism although it can be used similarly, at least to select existing names.

Answer (score 9):

It is because you don't want to use a wildcard. A `wildcard` is to select **existing** names.
(See [Filename Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html))

- `?` is a wildcard for any character, exactly once.
- `*` is a wildcard for any character, any number of times.
- `[]` is a character class wildcard, matching a class (a collection of one or more characters), once. Inside the brackets you set the allowed characters to match. `[1-300]` won't work.

`{...}` is what you want, but it is not a wildcard, it is called [**brace expansion**](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html).

Unfortunately, [some tutorials](https://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm) are wrong about it.

Comment: Oh, everything gained meaning in my mind right now thanks for your reply <3